# Is it computationally faster for browser to decrease than increase the size of an image?

Tags: html, image, image-processing, browser

Let say that I have an image with the size 200x200px. I also have two separate webpages. The first page has an image tag with the attributes `width="100" height="100"` so the image is downsampled by half. The second page has an image tag with the attributes `width="400" height="400"` so the image is oversampled to the double the original size.

Which one of the cases is computationally faster to execute? [Downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling) or [oversampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling). Other names for the operation would be subsampling and [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) or just decreasing image size and increasing it. My guts tell me that there is less to compute when decreasing the image size but I'm not sure.

It is true that with just one small image the difference is meaningless. And of course the best solution would be to avoid scaling of images in the first place. Nonetheless if the target application uses high number of constantly changing images in different scales and is used from a mobile device then knowing the difference might become valuable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that there will be quite a bit of variation from browser to browser, device to device, at least for reasonably small changes in size.  You also need to consider the time it takes to display these images, not just scale them.  I suggest that you benchmark it in a test that makes sense for your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Oversampling** is supposed to be more expensive... it **FOR SURE** requires some kind of interpolation. Let's suppose the simplest one: the [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)! It's already more expensive than calculating 'a single **mod** operator' (the only thing you need in order to do a downsampling). I don't think someone would do much different...

Trying to be more accurate about the browsers, let's consider that any modern browser uses some tricks like GPU and/or [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) (Multi-Processing) to render the images. But GPU requires upload data from CPU and it has a price. This data transfer is a narrow path. So, for small images, it's gonna be almost the same thing... no big difference!

Mobile devices don't have as many cores as a Desktop computer... so OpenMP is not gonna be much helpful for small images too.